# Is there any way to make a procedural blur on the Shader Editor that isn't so noisy?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, lighting, shader-nodes

I am looking for a way to do a procedural blur in Shader Editor (not compositing), and the current way that I see that is mostly used is to use White Noise Texture or a simple noise texture and mix it with the vector for the texture, but this always leaves the texture noisy and very inconvenient for rendering or baking.
Is there a less noisy way to do it? maybe some add-on or custom nodes?

Comment: You could use a convolution, like at https://blendswap.com/blend/20964 .  That's old, but it may still work, and in any case demonstrates the technique.

Comment: That's works perfectly! Thank you!